# Checking homomorphisms to be nullhomotopic between two topological groups

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

We were solving this problem.

> Describe all homomorphisms $g: S^{1} \to S^1 \times S^1$ which are null
> homotopic. Justify your answer.

We were unsure if it's homomorphism or homeomorphism, but it's been cleared that we can think of homomorphism between them as topological groups. But we don't know whether OP is talking about those homomorphisms which are induced by nullhomotopic maps or not. Even if so, how to solve this problem.

Any hint will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ be the canonical projections $S^1\times S^1\twoheadrightarrow S^1$.

Postcomposing with $\pi_j$ turns a nullhomotopy $g\simeq1_{S^1\to S^1\times S^1}$ into a nullhomotopy $g\simeq1_{S^1\to S^1}$.  Conversely, if each coordinate of $g$ is nullhomotopic, then "homotope first the $\pi_1$-coordinate, then the $\pi_2$-coordinate" is a nullhomotopy for $g$ as a whole.

But hom(e)omorphisms $S^1\to S^1$ are characterized by winding number.  So, ask yourself: which of those maps are nullhomotopic?

Comment: The constant map to the identity? The winding number has to be $0$ only.

Comment: @AnikBhowmick: Exactly.